# Let card content take the available height if necessary

Tags: html, css

I have a page that contains a card.
The card should take the automatic height which depends on its content, except when the content exceeds the height of the screen it is necessary to display a bare scroll.

In this case the title and the content will be scrollable but not the footer. the footer must always be displayed at the bottom of the page in fixed mode (when the content is large).

```css
.card {
  width: 80%;
  border: solid 2px #eee;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
<menu>
  <!-- Elements -->
</menu>
<!-- Elements -->
<!-- Elements -->
<div class="card">
  <p class="card-title">Title</p>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>
      Integer ullamcorper mi nec pellentesque ultricies. Sed vel efficitur augue. Cras fringilla non nisl convallis blandit. Nunc libero odio, tincidunt vitae sodales eu, pellentesque sed leo. Donec tempus erat sed leo vestibulum, eu fringilla ante dignissim.
      Fusce viverra interdum diam id lacinia. Nam tincidunt euismod quam, at pretium lorem mattis non. Nulla facilisi. Mauris sem massa, porttitor id nisl eu, placerat tincidunt turpis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis
      ultricies turpis eu mi facilisis, in venenatis lectus iaculis. In vitae augue nec neque pellentesque suscipit eget a est. Aenean dolor ex, vehicula sed bibendum eu, semper in sapien. In eget ante eu nulla scelerisque pharetra vitae tristique lacus.
      Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc at condimentum velit. Maecenas tempor efficitur lacus, eget bibendum quam dapibus ac. Cras hendrerit metus ac velit mollis, sed dignissim justo aliquet. Fusce eleifend pharetra lectus eget sodales. Quisque ac lacus mollis,
      sollicitudin ligula elementum, porttitor ex. Nulla facilisi. Donec ultricies iaculis dignissim. Pellentesque eu neque quis sapien porta ultricies. Quisque rhoncus pulvinar fringilla.
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button>
      Apply
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/psvhrx3q)

What's the most elegant way to do it? Preferably in full CSS/Sass.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `max-height` to `.card` and make the `.card-footer` a `sticky` element to follow the card when being scrollable in small screens.
http://jsfiddle.net/2d0Labwf

```css
.card {
  width: 80%;
  border: solid 2px #eee;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <p class="card-title">Title</p>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>
      Integer ullamcorper mi nec pellentesque ultricies. Sed vel efficitur augue. Cras fringilla non nisl convallis blandit. Nunc libero odio, tincidunt vitae sodales eu, pellentesque sed leo. Donec tempus erat sed leo vestibulum, eu fringilla ante dignissim. Fusce viverra interdum diam id lacinia. Nam tincidunt euismod quam, at pretium lorem mattis non. Nulla facilisi. Mauris sem massa, porttitor id nisl eu, placerat tincidunt turpis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis ultricies turpis eu mi facilisis, in venenatis lectus iaculis. In vitae augue nec neque pellentesque suscipit eget a est. Aenean dolor ex, vehicula sed bibendum eu, semper in sapien. In eget ante eu nulla scelerisque pharetra vitae tristique lacus.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc at condimentum velit. Maecenas tempor efficitur lacus, eget bibendum quam dapibus ac. Cras hendrerit metus ac velit mollis, sed dignissim justo aliquet. Fusce eleifend pharetra lectus eget sodales. Quisque ac lacus mollis, sollicitudin ligula elementum, porttitor ex. Nulla facilisi. Donec ultricies iaculis dignissim. Pellentesque eu neque quis sapien porta ultricies. Quisque rhoncus pulvinar fringilla.
</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button>
      Apply
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's almost what I'm trying to do
in my case I need to put the footer at `bottom: 100px`;
The remaining content remains displayed below the footer. Can we avoid this?
You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/w0vnpx74

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri Actually, I can't catch your idea. Why need to add a space between the footer and the end of the card? Do you another element below the footer with `100px` height?

Comment: I understand now. the problem I have now is the static definition of the `max-height:80vh;`. In my real case it's `50vh` but this value depends on the height of the content defined above on the card.
Is there a way to avoid this? i hope i am clear. If not I can give examples / screenshot.

Comment: You should define a `height` or `max-height` to activate the scrollbar to the card. We can calculate the height of the content to add instead of `50vh`, what is the max height of the content?
Sure, it will be helpful to share a screenshot or an example.

Comment: The problem here is that the `max-height` is statically defined with `60vh`. This will no longer work if the top content of the card is larger or smaller.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7eTG.png
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/u1ezw7s3

Comment: Good, let's read how many characters we have in the content and evaluate it to a height value. I will prepare an example for you if that suitable for you.

Comment: Thank you for the interest.
In my real case the content is not really text. It's Angular components. How can we go about calculating this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222787/discussion-between-abdelrhman-arnos-and-mouad-ennaciri).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `max-height` on the card content equal to the viewport height minus the height of the card header and footer by using calc. Then set the `overflow` to scroll.

This will ensure the card isn't taller than the viewport, the card footer always displays at the bottom, and the rest of the card content is scrollable.

```css
.card {
  width: 80%;
  border: solid 2px #eee;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.card-content {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 71px);
  overflow: scroll;
}
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
<menu>
  <!-- Elements -->
</menu>
<!-- Elements -->
<!-- Elements -->
<div class="card">
  <p class="card-title">Title</p>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>
      Integer ullamcorper mi nec pellentesque ultricies. Sed vel efficitur augue. Cras fringilla non nisl convallis blandit. Nunc libero odio, tincidunt vitae sodales eu, pellentesque sed leo. Donec tempus erat sed leo vestibulum, eu fringilla ante dignissim.
      Fusce viverra interdum diam id lacinia. Nam tincidunt euismod quam, at pretium lorem mattis non. Nulla facilisi. Mauris sem massa, porttitor id nisl eu, placerat tincidunt turpis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis
      ultricies turpis eu mi facilisis, in venenatis lectus iaculis. In vitae augue nec neque pellentesque suscipit eget a est. Aenean dolor ex, vehicula sed bibendum eu, semper in sapien. In eget ante eu nulla scelerisque pharetra vitae tristique lacus.
      Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc at condimentum velit. Maecenas tempor efficitur lacus, eget bibendum quam dapibus ac. Cras hendrerit metus ac velit mollis, sed dignissim justo aliquet. Fusce eleifend pharetra lectus eget sodales. Quisque ac lacus mollis,
      sollicitudin ligula elementum, porttitor ex. Nulla facilisi. Donec ultricies iaculis dignissim. Pellentesque eu neque quis sapien porta ultricies. Quisque rhoncus pulvinar fringilla.
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button>
      Apply
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```